# Too many re-renders React error while fetching data from API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch-api

I am building a simple recipe app and I have a problem with fetching my data from the API, because the code seems to run on every render and I do not even understand why it re-runs since I found that if I add the dependency array, it should run only once, right?

**App.js**

```
function App() {
  const [recipesList, setRecipesList] = useState([]);
  let [scroll, setScroll] = useState(0)



console.log(recipesList,"list");

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <a href="index.html"><img className="logo" src={logo} alt="Logo"/></a>
      <Recipes recipesList={recipesList}  getRecipes={setRecipesList} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**Recipes.js**

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from "react";
import Recipe from "../Recipe/Recipe";
import "./Recipes.css";

const Recipes = (props) => {

useEffect( () => {
    if (props.recipesList.length === 0) {
        fetch("myapi.com/blablabla")
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(result => {
            props.getRecipes(result.recipes);
            }
        )
    }
    else {
        console.log("Do not fetch");
    }
    return () => console.log("unmounting");
        
}, [props])




const recipeComponent = props.recipesList.map( (item) => {
        return <Recipe className="recipe" info={item}/>
    })
    return(
        <div className="recipes">
            {recipeComponent}
            <h1>Hello</h1>
        </div>
    )
}


export default Recipes;
```

Answer (score 1):

try this code :

```
function App() {
  const [recipesList, setRecipesList] = useState([]);
  let [scroll, setScroll] = useState(0)

const getListPropd = (e) => {
setRecipesList(e)
}
console.log(recipesList,"list");

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <a href="index.html"><img className="logo" src={logo} alt="Logo"/></a>
      <Recipes recipesList={(e) => getListPropd (e)}  getRecipes={setRecipesList} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

```
const [checkData , setCheckData ] = useState(true)

useEffect( () => {
    if (checkData) {
        fetch("myapi.com/blablabla")
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(result => {
            props.recipesList(result.recipes);
            }
        if(props.recipesList.length > 0) {
          setCheckData(false)
         }
        )
   
    else {
        console.log("Do not fetch");
    }


    return () => console.log("unmounting");
        
}, [checkData])
```

Answer (score 1):

Components will re-render every time your the props or state changes inside of the component.

I would recommend keeping the *fetching* logic inside of the `Recipes` component, because A: its recipe related data, not app related data. And B: this way you can control the state in `Recipes` instead of the props. This will give you more control on how the component behaves instead of being dependent on the parent component.

In the `useEffect` hook, leave the dependency array empty. This will cause the component to render, call `useEffect` only the first time, load your data and then render the recipes without re-rendering further.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import Recipe from "../Recipe/Recipe";
import "./Recipes.css";

const Recipes = () => {
  const [recipesList, setRecipesList] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("myapi.com/blablabla")
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((result) => {
        setRecipesList(result.recipes);
      });

    return () => console.log("unmounting");
  }, []);

  // On the first render recipeComponents will be empty.
  const recipeComponents = recipesList.map((item) => <Recipe className="recipe" info={item}/>)

  return (
    <div className="recipes">
      {recipeComponents}
      <h1>Hello</h1>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Recipes;
```

Comment: I used your code in useEffect but I still get the same error :/

Comment: Try to make a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) in which we can run your code. This snippet above should not be responsible for any unnecessary rerenders.

Comment: When the fake api adress is used, everything seems fine and does load the page, however if I use my real api, then I get the error with rerendering. Here is the 
 codesandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/zen-heyrovsky-zqgum?file=/src/Recipes.js

Comment: UPDATE: I editted the sanbox a little bit but a weird thing seems to take place. When I console log the data, it is showing it is undefined, why is that ?

Comment: It's because an arrow function without curly braces implicitly returns `res.json()`. If you do add the curly braces, then you need to add a `return` statement inside that block. Otherwise in the next `.then()` callback, there will be no passed value, thus `data` is `undefined`.

Comment: Alright, so I added the return, but I still get the same rerender error.

Comment: When I try your link, the code won't even run because files are missing. Are you still working in the same code sandbox?

Comment: I somehow figured it out and it is perfectly working now ! I think the problem was in the child Recipe.js, but thank you very much for the help

Answer (score 0):

the useEffect hook uses an empty dependency array, [] if it should ONLY run once after component is mounted. This is the equivalent of the old lifecycle method componentDidMount()

If you add a non-empty dependency array, then the component rerenders EVERY time this changes. In this case, every time your component receives new props (i.e. from a parent component, this triggers a reload.

see more info here https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html , especially the yellow block at the bottom of the page

Happy coding!